# Making sense of 'OFFSET/FETCH' in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, fetch, offset, sql-server-2012

Just installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 today. In familiarizing myself with the pagination feature addition of ORDER BY, I keep running into this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT SingleWomansName, NumberOfCats
    FROM CatLadies
    WHERE NumberOfCats > 1
    ORDER BY NumberOfCats
    OFFSET 10 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

I've seen plenty of how-to articles with similar syntax. What gives?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx

Comment: You said you installed SSMS 2012 today. Are you also connecting to a 2012 SQL server? As this syntax is new to 2012, if you connect to a 2008 (etc) instance, it won't work.

Comment: For others who are certain they are querying a 2012 instance and still getting the error, the order by clause is required.

Answer (score 3):

Are you positive you are connected to a SQL Server 2012 database? The following works:

```
Select Name, CatCount
From CatLadies
Order By Name
Offset 2 Rows 
Fetch Next 2 Rows Only
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10e8f/1)

I do get the error you are seeing when I switch to SQL Server 2008

[SQL Fiddle using SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10e8f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database compatibility level is set to SQL Server 2012 (110).