# Getting Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET' error in NHibernate.Linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

I am getting following error in my `ASP.NET MVC 4.0` Application with `NHibernate v4.0.0 (.Net Framework 4.0)`. This error shows in `NHibernate.Linq` query

```
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.
```

**IN THIS LINE**

```
Line 23:         public IList<Post> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize)
Line 24:         {
Line 25:             var posts = _session.Query<Post>()  //here
Line 26:                                   .Where(p => p.Published) 
Line 27:                                   .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
```

***I have found some similar posts on SO and on other sites. but, they are suggesting that use SQL SERVER 2012 instead of 2008.*** Yes my sql server version is `2008`. but, I have created another application using `ASP.NET MVC 5 (.Net Framework 4.5)` and `NHibernate v3.3.1` and it works great in same database and same sql server version.

**Some similar post:**

1. [“Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'” modift sql comm 2012 to 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617714/3761928)
2. [Pagination query for mssql server 2008 Throwing Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15564219/3761928)
3. [Making sense of 'OFFSET/FETCH' in SSMS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270373/3761928)

So, I don't think that the problem is in my sql server version at least in my case.

I am not executing sql query directly into ssms or through command object. I am using `NHibernate.Linq` query.

**Full NHibernate Query:**

```
 var posts = _session.Query<Post>()
                              .Where(p => p.Published)
                              .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                              .Take(pageSize)
                              .Fetch(p => p.Category)
                              .ToList();
```

How do I solve this problem. Please guide me.

Please ask me for more information if it is insufficient.

Thanks !!

Comment: If you have grandchildren collections than use `fetchmany` instead `fetch`

Comment: `Fetch` should be used for the references and `fetchmany` for the collections

Comment: yes but, as I have mentioned in my question the same code and same work is working fine for different NHibernate version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems, that NHibernate is just wrongly instructed to use dialect related to SQL Serer 2012

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
```

Just set it to 2008

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
```

and it will NOT use features from a later version [Implement paging (skip / take) functionality with this query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13220743/1679310)

Comment: Thanks @Radim you just solve my query. You are right i have configured sql server version for NHibernate incorrectly.

Comment: Glad to see NHibernate is working for you. Good luck it is amazing tool ;)

Comment: same problem with EF. Check for the `ProviderManifestToken` tag in your edmx files.

Comment: oh, and yeah, "Update Model" will also update "ProviderManifestToken" automatically! So keep an eye on this file most importantly if the version of sql server you are using in your development environment is different than the live one.